# rails post after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, post, controller

i've got a site, which has a login system.

here's my scenario:

- user is not logged in
- fills in a form to submit data
- before the create action, i check if the user is logged in.
- if the user is not logged in, they are prompted to sign up and log in..
- upon sign up / login the form is submitted and the form data saved without prompting the user to save it again.

In order to do this, I need to use a redirect_to, specify the controller and action, however, this requires a POST, and I don't believe you can post variables on a redirect.

any ideas of a work around, which would keep the current user flow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some options you might want to try:

- Perform the user registration using AJAX, so you never have to leave the page and won't need a redirect
- Store the form data to a 'temporary' user account, then update the account to 'real' with the user registration info. You may want to occasionally clean out old 'temporary user' data that never completed the registration.
- Convert the form data to serialized form and pass it along with the redirect as a url parameter (only works for a guaranteed small amount of data)
- Store the form data in the session (last resort, only use if your traffic will remain relatively low, as you may end up running into scalability issues)

Comment: sounds like point 2 would be a way to go. slightly open to abuse, though.

Comment: Yep agreed. Point 1 and 2 are ideal.